# How to write program during compiling?

Tags: c

Write a small C program, which while compiling takes another program
from input terminal, and on running gives the result for the second
program. (NOTE: The key is, think UNIX).

Suppose, the program is 1.c
Then, while compiling

```
$ cc -o 1 1.c
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
}
^D
$ ./1
Hello World
$
```

Comment: Doesnt the title count as a question?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is an old parlaour trick I guess

My program, tty.c:

```
#include "/dev/tty"
```

Shell:

```
$ gcc tty.c
int main() {
printf("Hey\n");
} *Ctrl-D here*
In file included from tty.c:1:
/dev/tty: In function ‘main’:
/dev/tty:2: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
$./a.out 
Hey
```

Comment: Thats really a suprising answer ... never thought there is such a way to do things ...

Answer (score 1):

The most reasonable way to make *compilation* read a file would be `#include`, but it's not obvious to me how to make it read standard input in a portable way on all Unix systems (easy in Linux, thanks to the magic of `/proc`!, but that wouldn't be portable).